# Google Earth Engine SNIC Segmentation tilescale error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-segmentation

I am very new to Google Earth Engine and object based image analysis.

First of all, I am trying to do image segmentation using the SNIC algorithm.

This is my code and I got " Tile error: Output of image computation is too large (12 bands for 3513510 pixels = 321.7 MiB > 80.0 MiB).
If this is a reduction, try specifying a larger 'tileScale' parameter." error.

How do I get over it?

I already set the tilescale parameter to 16

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR');

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 3000,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};
 
var filtered = s2
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-08-25', '2021-08-29'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
  .select('B.*');


var composite = filtered.median().clip(geometry) ;

// Display the input composite.
Map.addLayer(composite, rgbVis, 'image');

///SNIC


var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(36);
var snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: composite,
  compactness: 0.2,
  connectivity: 8,
  neighborhoodSize: 64,
  size: 50,
  seeds: seeds,
}).reproject({
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 10
});


Map.addLayer(snic.randomVisualizer(), null, "snic")

/////vector
var clusters_snic = snic.select("clusters")

var vectors = clusters_snic.reduceToVectors({
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  scale: 10,
  tileScale:   16,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  geometry: geometry,
});


var empty = ee.Image().byte();


var outline = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: vectors,
  color: 1,
  width: 1
});
Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'segments');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is related to the `reproject()` call you've added to the SNIC results.  Don't do that.  The `reduceToVectors` call has its own scale and that's the scale that will be used to generate the vectors.

(Although, why you're vectorizing just to re-compute a raster is still a question).

Comment: I actually use the reproject() function for the inconsistency in the SNIC algorithm. Everytime I change scale, it recalculate and give me a new result. I applied it because I saw the solution in this link. (gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333413/…) .. I got the code in the link from Medium and tried to update it with AOI and training data for my study area.  I am trying to classify burn area. (https://joaootavionf007.medium.com/object-based-image-analysis-on-google-earth-engine-1b80e9cb7312). And Please see link to my code : https://code.earthengine.google.com/7fd31965ef570678c5d6202116e83315